# How can i get Culture by LCID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo

In my application (MVC3) i have bind culture info list to dropdown and as per selection i have stored [LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid.aspx) value in DB. now i would like to get Culture using LCID, **how can i obtain using LCID value?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the CultureInfo constructor:

```
 new CultureInfo(myLCID);
```

This will return a CultureInfo object for the appropriate LCID.

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.-ctor#system-globalization-cultureinfo-ctor(system-int32)

Comment: thanks i have read about that class in msdn but did not look at constructors! thanks a lot again